# Can C# ASPX pages access a class method directly?

Tags: c#, .net, class

This works this fine, the problem is I want this on a number of pages and don't want to keep repeating the CS code which communicates with the class.

The variable reference in the ASPX page:

```
<%:countVal %>
```

Code Behind:

```
public string countVal = "";
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  reviewCount count = new reviewCount();
  countVal = count.reviewCounts().ToString();
}
```

and the method:

```
public int reviewCounts()
{
    int fbCount = 10;
    int googleCount = 10;

    int total = fbCount + googleCount;

    return total;
}
```

Would it be possible to skip the middle skep and manipulate this `<%:countVal %>` to grab the data directly from the class?

Newish to C#, so sorry if the answer is blatent.

Comment: reviewCounts is not a class.. its a method and as all its parts are private, no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `reviewCounts()` method isn't a class, it's a method. You can not instantiate a method and then access a method on that method.

Instead you will have to put this reviewCounts method in an actual class. Since you only provided mockup code and I don't know if you actually need instances to calculate your reviewCounts I'll give you this example:

```
static class ReviewCount
{
  public static int ReviewCounts
  {
    get
    {
      int fbCount = 10;
      int googleCount = 10;

      int total = fbCount + googleCount;

      return total;
    }
  }
}
```

Then use `<%: ReviewCounts.ReviewCounts %>` to get the value from this property from any aspx page.

Comment: This errors with: "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type"

Comment: @GerryHodson right, that means the class name is the same as the method name, which doesn't work. simply rename either the class or method, I've edited the code sample so the class is called ReviewCount instead.

Comment: Works, thank you! I'd change `<%: ReviewCounts.ReviewCounts %>` so it's correct also!